# Correct format for separating declaration and definition of C++ template functions

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I'm using this method http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl.html to separate the definition of a C++ template function from its declaration, to avoid cluttering up my header files with code.

The link uses as an example a function with no arguments or return, but suppose I have a function with an argument. The link would suggest the following arrangement:

```
// File "f.h" 
template <typename T> void f(T t);
```

---

```
// File "f.cpp"
#include "f.h"

template <typename T> void f(T t) {
  // do something
}

template void f<int>(int t);
// other specializations as needed
```

However it seems the specialization also works if you omit the type in angle brackets, as I suppose the compiler deduces it from the argument type:

```
template void f(int t);
```

But I'm wondering, is it valid to do that?

Visual C++ 12 (2013)

Comment: Doesn't work in g++ 4.7.3. I wonder if that's a g++ bug.

Comment: @RSahu, works fine for me with 4.7.3

Comment: N.B. this question is not directly about separating declaration and definition, it's about the syntax of explicit instantiation. The question and answer would be pretty much the same if everything was in the header (although you might use `extern` to make it an explicit instantiation declaration if it was in the header)

Comment: Perfect, thank you for a speedy and concise answer :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's valid. [temp.explicit] p3 says:

> If the explicit instantiation is for a function or member function, the *unqualified-
>   id* in the *declaration* shall be either a *template-id* or, where all template arguments can be deduced, a *template-name* or *operator-function-id*.

Your function has one template parameter and it can be deduced from the function argument, when the function parameter is `int` the template argument can be deduced as `int`, so you can (optionally) use the *template-name*, `f`, instead of the *template-id* `f<int>`.